# secondaryBody SlotLayout "Cannot emit new states after calling close"

Tags: flutter, adaptive-layout

I am creating an app that has `small` and `mediumAndUp` displays
I want a List-Detail structure that behaves like this
in `small` :

- Display list of items
- when tap on an item push a new screen to show the detail

in `mediumAndUp`:

- Display in half the screen the list of items, and in the other half of the screen the details
- when tap on an item, update the other half of the screen with the details uf such item

I am using `flutter_adaptive_scaffold` library

so far This is my code:

home_page.dart

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({
    super.key,
    required String tab,
  }): index = tabs.indexWhere((element) => element.name == tab);

  static const pageConfig = PageConfig(
    icon: Icons.home,
    name: homeRoute,
  );

  final int index;

  static const tabs = [
    RacesPage.pageConfig,
    ReportsPage.pageConfig,
  ];

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final destinations = HomePage.tabs.map(
      (page) => NavigationDestination(
          icon: Icon(page.icon),
          label: page.name,
      )
  ).toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: AdaptiveLayout(
          primaryNavigation: SlotLayout(... ),
          bottomNavigation: SlotLayout(...),
          body: SlotLayout(
            config: <Breakpoint, SlotLayoutConfig>{
              Breakpoints.small: SlotLayout.from(
                  key: const Key('primary-body-small'),
                  builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: const Text('Centinelas'),
                      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                      elevation: 8.0,
                      actions: [
                        Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                context.goNamed(ProfilePage.pageConfig.name,);
                              },
                              child: const Icon(
                                Icons.person_2_rounded,
                                size: 26.0,
                              ),
                            )
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    body: HomePage.tabs[widget.index].child,
                  )
              ),
              Breakpoints.mediumAndUp: SlotLayout.from(
                  key: const Key('primary-body-medium-up'),
                  builder: (_) => HomePage.tabs[widget.index].child
              ),
            },
          ),
          secondaryBody: SlotLayout(
            config: <Breakpoint, SlotLayoutConfig>{
              Breakpoints.mediumAndUp: SlotLayout.from(
                  key: const Key('secondary-body-medium'),
                  builder: widget.index != 0 ? null : (_) =>
                      BlocBuilder<NavigationCubit, NavigationCubitState>(
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          final selectedRaceId = state.selectedRaceId;
                          final isSecondBodyDisplayed = Breakpoints.mediumAndUp.isActive(context);

                          context.read<NavigationCubit>().secondBodyHasChanged(
                            isSecondBodyDisplayed: isSecondBodyDisplayed,
                          );

                          if(selectedRaceId == null){
                            return const Center();
                          }
                          return RaceDetailPageProvider(
                            key: Key(selectedRaceId.value),
                            raceEntryIdString: selectedRaceId.value,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
              )
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
void tapOnNavigationDestination(BuildContext context, int index) =>
      context.go('/$homeRoute/${HomePage.tabs[index].name}');
}
```

navigation_cubit.dart

```
class NavigationCubit extends Cubit<NavigationCubitState>{
  NavigationCubit(): super(const NavigationCubitState());

  void selectedRaceChanged(RaceEntryId raceEntryId){
    emit(NavigationCubitState(selectedRaceId: raceEntryId));
  }

  void secondBodyHasChanged({required bool isSecondBodyDisplayed}) {
    if (state.isSecondBodyDisplayed != isSecondBodyDisplayed) {
      emit(NavigationCubitState(
        isSecondBodyDisplayed: isSecondBodyDisplayed,
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

routes.dart

```
final routes = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
  initialLocation: '/${SessionPage.pageConfig.name}',
  observers: [GoRouterObserver()],
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: SessionPage.pageConfig.name,
      path: '/${SessionPage.pageConfig.name}',
      builder: (context, state) => BlocProvider<auth.AuthCubit>(
        create: (context) => serviceLocator<auth.AuthCubit>(),
        child: const SessionPage(),
      ),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: LoginPage.pageConfig.name,
      path: '/${LoginPage.pageConfig.name}',
      builder: (context, state) => SignInScreen(...),
    GoRoute(
      name: ProfilePage.pageConfig.name,
      path: '/${ProfilePage.pageConfig.name}',
      builder: (context, state) => Scaffold(...),
    ),
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: shellNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) => child,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          name: HomePage.pageConfig.name,
          path: '/$homeRoute/:tab',
          builder: (context, state) => HomePage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            tab: state.pathParameters['tab']!,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: RaceDetailPage.pageConfig.name,
      path: '/$homeRoute/$racesRoute/:raceEntryId',
      builder: (context, state) {
        return BlocListener<NavigationCubit, NavigationCubitState>(
          listenWhen: (previous, current) => previous.isSecondBodyDisplayed != current.isSecondBodyDisplayed,
          listener: (context, state){
            if(context.canPop() && (state.isSecondBodyDisplayed ?? false )){
              context.pop();
            }
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Detalles de carrera'),
              leading: BackButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  if(context.canPop()){
                    context.pop();
                  } else {
                    context.goNamed(
                      HomePage.pageConfig.name,
                      pathParameters: {'tab' : RacesPage.pageConfig.name},
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            body: RaceDetailPageProvider(
              raceEntryIdString: state.pathParameters['raceEntryId'] ?? '',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    ),
  ],
);
```

race_entry_item_view_loaded.dart

```
class RaceEntryItemViewLoaded extends StatelessWidget {
  const RaceEntryItemViewLoaded({
    super.key,
    required this.raceEntry,
  });

  final RaceEntry raceEntry;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<NavigationCubit, NavigationCubitState>(
      buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
      previous.selectedRaceId != current.selectedRaceId,
      builder: (context, state){
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Material(
            elevation: 8.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(...),
              child: ListTile(... ),
                onTap: (){
                  debugPrint('onTap race:${raceEntry.id.value}');
                  context.read<NavigationCubit>().selectedRaceChanged(raceEntry.id);
                  if(Breakpoints.small.isActive(context)){
                    debugPrint('small: ${raceEntry.id.value}');
                    context.pushNamed(
                      RaceDetailPage.pageConfig.name,
                      pathParameters: {
                        'raceEntryId': raceEntry.id.value.toString(),
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

race_detail_bloc.dart

```
class RaceDetailBloc extends Bloc<RaceDetailEvent, RaceDetailState> {
  RaceDetailBloc({
    required this.loadRaceFullUseCase,
  }) : super(const RaceDetailLoadingState());

  final LoadRaceFullUseCase loadRaceFullUseCase;

  Future<void> readRaceFull(RaceEntryId raceEntryId) async{
    emit(const RaceDetailLoadingState());
    try{
      final raceFull = await loadRaceFullUseCase.call(raceEntryId);
      if(raceFull.isRight){
        emit(const RaceDetailErrorState());
      } else {
        emit(RaceDetailLoadedState(raceFull: raceFull.left));
      }
    }catch(exception) {
      debugPrint(exception.toString());
      emit(const RaceDetailErrorState());
    }
  }

  @override
  Stream<int> mapEventToState(RaceDetailEvent event) async* {
    debugPrint('mapEventToState ${event.toString()}');
  }

  @override
  void onEvent(RaceDetailEvent event) {
    debugPrint('onEvent ${event.toString()}');
  }
}
```

The app works as expected in `small`
displays correctly, but in `mediumAndUp` I get the next error:

```
I/flutter (17477): Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close
E/flutter (17477): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot emit new states after calling close
E/flutter (17477): #0      BlocBase.emit (package:bloc/src/bloc_base.dart:97:9)
E/flutter (17477): #1      Bloc.emit (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:154:35)
E/flutter (17477): #2      RaceDetailBloc.readRaceFull (package:centinelas_app/application/pages/race_detail/bloc/race_detail_bloc.dart:31:7)
```

The odd thing is
If I run the webapp
And select any item from the `small` display, the detail is pushed correctly, then if resize the window to be `mediumAndUp` the detail is displayed correctly in the `secondaryuBody`
But it will throw the exception described above if I tap a list item from `mediumAndUp`